# How to subtract two different columns based on if the datetime equals eachother

Tags: pandas, datetime, calculated-columns

I have two dataframes both of which are organized by datetime:

First dataframe is data: has 113434 rows x 14 columns
[Data dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mq9uB.png)

Second dataframe is salcal: has 34 rows x 4 columns
[salcal dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZKRBj.png)

I am trying to write a code if the datetime is the same between data frames, subtract one column from the data dataframe from the salcal dataframe. I want to end up with a dataframe of 34 responses that would look something like this:
[Desired Outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gkNmq.png)

etc.

Thanks!

Comment: please provide an explicit, minimal reproducible example

Comment: Hi Mozway, I just updated my original comment. Sorry I am very new to stackoverflow and coding (if you can't tell). Hope that helps?

Answer (score 0):

Without a minimal reproducible example like [mozway](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16343464/mozway) commented, it's pretty much a shot in the dark, but if I understood correctly your problem, something like this might work:

```py
import pandas as pd

result = (
    data.merge(salcal, on="datetime", how="inner")
    .assign(
        oxygen_diff=lambda xdf: xdf["02 Data (ml.l)"] - xdf["Oxygen (ml/l)"]
    )
    .groupby("datetime", as_index=False)
    .agg({"oxygen_diff": sum})
)
# Returns:
#
#               datetime  oxygen_diff
# 0  2021-07-01 04:18:23     0.999617
# 1  2021-07-01 05:38:39     0.220408
# 2  2021-07-01 06:42:58     0.510992
# 3  2021-07-01 06:45:54     0.212000
# 4  2021-07-01 10:38:20    -0.423491
# 5  2021-07-01 17:53:12     0.526640
# 6  2021-07-02 02:46:59     0.343579
# 7  2021-07-02 15:35:10    -1.276152
# 8  2021-07-02 16:08:02    -1.075247
# 9  2021-07-02 16:42:00     0.075583
# 10 2021-07-02 17:16:24    -0.149142
# 11 2021-07-02 17:18:47     0.056838
```

If you want to output all 34 rows from `salcal`, you can change the `how` parameter from `data.merge` to `how="right"`, and then include a `.fillna(0)` right afterwards:

```py
result = (
    data.merge(salcal, on="datetime", how="right")
    .fillna(0)
    .assign(
        oxygen_diff=lambda xdf: xdf["02 Data (ml.l)"] - xdf["Oxygen (ml/l)"]
    )
    .groupby("datetime", as_index=False)
    .agg({"oxygen_diff": sum})
)
result
# Returns:
#
#               datetime  oxygen_diff
# 0  2021-07-01 02:50:27    -0.206559
# 1  2021-07-01 04:18:23     0.999617
# 2  2021-07-01 04:28:31    -0.100907
# 3  2021-07-01 05:38:39     0.220408
# 4  2021-07-01 06:42:58     0.510992
# 5  2021-07-01 06:45:54     0.212000
# 6  2021-07-01 07:35:47    -0.232744
# 7  2021-07-01 10:38:20    -0.423491
# 8  2021-07-01 11:42:48    -0.838348
# 9  2021-07-01 11:55:23    -0.954686
# 10 2021-07-01 12:31:01    -0.686616
# 11 2021-07-01 14:42:06    -0.787848
# 12 2021-07-01 15:34:51    -0.689417
# 13 2021-07-01 16:12:14    -0.004688
# 14 2021-07-01 17:30:34    -0.031746
# 15 2021-07-01 17:53:12     0.526640
# 16 2021-07-01 18:15:47    -0.468062
# 17 2021-07-01 19:07:46    -0.896544
# 18 2021-07-01 20:13:23    -0.006862
# 19 2021-07-01 22:07:00    -0.394853
# 20 2021-07-02 02:46:59     0.343579
# 21 2021-07-02 03:22:07    -0.801174
# 22 2021-07-02 09:20:54    -0.252222
# 23 2021-07-02 14:14:11    -0.933416
# 24 2021-07-02 15:06:25    -0.006612
# 25 2021-07-02 15:35:10    -1.276152
# 26 2021-07-02 16:08:02    -1.075247
# 27 2021-07-02 16:42:00     0.075583
# 28 2021-07-02 17:11:04    -0.128356
# 29 2021-07-02 17:16:24    -0.149142
# 30 2021-07-02 17:18:47     0.056838
# 31 2021-07-02 20:23:31    -0.358831
# 32 2021-07-02 20:55:24    -0.572195
# 33 2021-07-02 23:28:30    -0.178231
```

### Full Example

```py
from __future__ import annotations
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


def random_dates(
    start_date: str | pd.Timestamp,
    end_date: str | pd.Timestamp,
    size: int = 10,
) -> pd.DatetimeIndex:
    """Generate random dates between two dates.

    Parameters
    ----------
    start_date : str | pd.Timestamp
        Start date.
    end_date : str | pd.Timestamp
        End date.
    size : int, optional
        Number of dates to generate, by default 10.

    Returns
    -------
    pd.DatetimeIndex
        Random dates.

    Examples
    --------
    >>> random_dates("2020-01-01", "2020-01-31", size=5) # doctest: +ELLIPSIS
    DatetimeIndex(['2020-01-05', '2020-01-12', ...], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
    """
    start_u = pd.to_datetime(start_date).value // 10**9
    end_u = pd.to_datetime(end_date).value // 10**9
    return pd.to_datetime(np.random.randint(start_u, end_u, size), unit="s")

start_date = "2021-07-01 00:00:00"
end_date = "2021-07-03 00:00:00"

data = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "datetime": random_dates(start_date, end_date, 113_434),
        "02 Data (ml.l)": np.random.random(113_434),
    }
)
salcal = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "datetime": random_dates(start_date, end_date, 34),
        "Oxygen (ml/l)": np.random.random(34),
    }
)
result = (
    data.merge(salcal, on="datetime", how="inner")
    .assign(
        oxygen_diff=lambda xdf: xdf["02 Data (ml.l)"] - xdf["Oxygen (ml/l)"]
    )
    .groupby("datetime", as_index=False)
    .agg({"oxygen_diff": sum})
)
# Or:
result = (
    data.merge(salcal, on="datetime", how="right")
    .fillna(0)
    .assign(
        oxygen_diff=lambda xdf: xdf["02 Data (ml.l)"] - xdf["Oxygen (ml/l)"]
    )
    .groupby("datetime", as_index=False)
    .agg({"oxygen_diff": sum})
)
```